# Dynamically create matrix from a vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a matrix of shape Nx3 where N is not known at first.
This is what I'm basically trying to do:

```
    F = np.array([[],[],[]])
    for contact in contacts:
        xp,yp,theta = contact
        # Create vectors for points and normal
        P = [xp, yp, 0]
        N = [np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta), 0]
        # Calculate vector product
        cross_PN = np.cross(P,N)
        # f = [mz, fx, fi]
        mz = cross_PN[2]
        fx = N[0]
        fy = N[1]
        f = np.array([mz, fx, fy])
        F = np.vstack([F, f])
```

But this code doesn't work.
I can do similar thing in Matlab very easily, but that is not the case in Python using numpy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

I would like to create a matrix by adding new rows, but in the beginning the matrix is empty.
That is why I receive the error:
"along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 3"

Comment: Please provide some examples for `contacts`.

Comment: How about starting with `F = np.array([]).reshape(0, 3)`?

Comment: MATLAB allows you to 'grow' arrays (whether that's the most efficient way is another question).  In python it is more efficient to 'grow' lists, and make the array with one function call at the end.  In your example the repeated `vstack` is inefficient (assuming you get the starting case right), since it has to make a new array each time, with a growing amount of copying.

Comment: Doesn't `len(contacts)` tell you `N`?

Comment: Somebody suggested to use: F = np.empty((0,3)) and it indeed works.
However, since using vstack is an inefficient way, I may indeed use len(contacts) to get a number or contacts and maybe use preallocation in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and suggestion, I guess the correct and more efficient way to do this is the following:

```
L = len(contacts)
F = np.zeros((L, 3))
for ii in range(L):
    xp,yp,theta = contacts[ii]
    # Create vectors for points and normal
    P = [xp, yp, 0]
    N = [np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta), 0]
    # Calculate vector product
    cross_PN = np.cross(P,N)
    # f = [mz, fx, fi]
    mz = cross_PN[2]
    fx = N[0]
    fy = N[1]
    fi = np.array([mz, fx, fy])
    F[ii] = fi
```